# Xamarin xaml trying to get text labels underneath each other in a frame

Tags: xaml, user-interface, xamarin

I am trying to get text labels underneath each other in a frame, but the text behaves really strange and nothing that I tried works.

I am using this code:

```
<AbsoluteLayout>
<Frame HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" TranslationY="285" TranslationX="10" HeightRequest="70" WidthRequest="120">
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="0" Spacing="-10" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="green">
        <Image Source="mark_red.png" Scale="0.5" TranslationX="-20" TranslationY="-25"/>
        <Label Text="Voeding" FontSize="20" TranslationX="-20"/>
        <Label Text="Test" FontSize="20" TranslationY="-40"/>
    </StackLayout>
</Frame>

<Frame HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" TranslationY="415" TranslationX="10" HeightRequest="70" WidthRequest="120" >
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="0" Spacing="5" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <Image Source="mark_green.png" Scale="0.5" TranslationX="-20" TranslationY="-25"/>
        <Label Text="Sport" FontSize="20" TranslationX="-35"/>
    </StackLayout>

</Frame>

<Frame HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" TranslationY="285" TranslationX="190" HeightRequest="70" WidthRequest="120">
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="0" Spacing="5" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <Image Source="mark_blue.png" Scale="0.5" TranslationX="-20" TranslationY="-25"/>
        <Label Text="Slaap" FontSize="20" TranslationX="-35"/>
    </StackLayout>
</Frame>

<Frame HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" TranslationY="415" TranslationX="190" HeightRequest="70" WidthRequest="120">
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="0" Spacing="-45" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <Image Source="mark_orange.png" Scale="0.5" TranslationX="-20" TranslationY="-25"/>
        <Label Text="Huidige tijd" FontSize="20" TranslationX="15"/>
    </StackLayout>

</Frame>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Output

[image: output]

I want the text "Test" to display in the frame underneath the text "Voeding". I made the background green to see the height and the width of the box. How should I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap each frame in another stack layout to get another row. Also get rid of some of the Translations. I use those very sparingly. They will not translate to different screen sizes very well.

```
   <Frame HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" TranslationY="285" TranslationX="10" HeightRequest="70" WidthRequest="120">
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">   
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="0"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Green">
                <Image Source="mark_red.png" Scale="0.5" TranslationX="-20" TranslationY="-25"/>
                <Label Text="Voeding" FontSize="20"/>                
            </StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Test" FontSize="20" />
        </StackLayout>
    </Frame>
```

If i coding this I would start with a grid with two rows and two columns and then put stack layouts inside the proper grid cell.

```
<Grid Margin="20" ColumnSpacing="10" RowSpacing="10">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="120"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="120"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackLayout Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Padding="10" BackgroundColor="White">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">                 
                <BoxView HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="10" BackgroundColor="Red"/>
                <Label Text="Voeding" FontSize="20"/>                
            </StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Test" FontSize="20" />
    </StackLayout>

    <StackLayout Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Padding="10" BackgroundColor="White">
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <BoxView HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="10" BackgroundColor="Green"/>
            <Label Text="Sport" FontSize="20" />
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>

    <StackLayout Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Padding="10" BackgroundColor="White">
        <StackLayout  Orientation="Horizontal">
            <BoxView HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="10" BackgroundColor="Blue"/>
            <Label Text="Slaap" FontSize="20" />
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>

    <StackLayout Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Padding="10" BackgroundColor="White">
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <BoxView HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="10" BackgroundColor="Orange"/>
            <Label Text="Huidige tijd" FontSize="20" />
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</Grid>
```

I replaced your images with boxes since I didn't have them.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but how do I get the same but than with using frames?

Comment: Use my first code snippet I place of your first frame. From there you can modify your other three to match.

Comment: Just curious why do you want to use a frame?

Comment: Because I like the drop shadows of the frames

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but with your first code snippet, I'm getting the following result:
https://i.gyazo.com/5b1b1beac01cfd9d7833ec96c8b21f96.jpg

The frame underneath is from your code, but it doesn't look like it's supposed to be.

Comment: @JipHarthoorn With you initial posted code and my code for the first frame I get. The following [https://ibb.co/dv13yL](https://ibb.co/dv13yL)   There must be something else on you form that is causing it to not show the text.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. It worked when I addes `<Absolutelayout>`, but the image in front of the text isn't displaying like it is in my post. Do you know how I could modify `<Image Source="mark_red.png"/>` to my expectation?

Comment: Can you post the image somewhere? I will use it and get it working for you.